# Firefox : Overlaying commondialog.xul

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to suppress all modal dialogs in Firefox through an extension, either brought up by content or chrome, for my automated testing. Is there a way to do that? Someone recommended that overlaying CommonDialog.xul might get me some ways there. Any suggestions on how to go about doing that? Any examples will be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Sunil

Answer (score 0):

I found a notification fired by Firefox called 'common-dialog-loaded' and 'tabmodal-dialog-loaded' that can be used for this purpose.